# Why is my meteor app taking so long to load?

Tags: javascript, meteor, google-chrome-devtools

Can you give some tips of what and where to check in order to improve my Meteor app loading performance?  Currently my app is taking almost 15 seconds to load completely, which is insane.

I see the major loading time is in scripting (yellow) and the XHR bar is taking almost 6 seconds.

[image: loading performance chart]

When I click on the scripts I can't get to my script names in order to review loops and indexes.  All I see are function calls with function names not related to my own code, probably related to packages.  Function names are like: 
`s.xhr.onreadystatechange @ afaec39….js?meteor_js_resource=true:60`

I have checked my subs/pubs and all of them are available on client within the first second.

Comment: xhr will be `Meteor.method()` calls or ajax requests. You can drill down into those big xhr calls and see the actual method names that are being called, that should give you some clues. Look at the number of bytes transferred for the initial page as well.

Comment: The page is loading 420Kb now.  I just trimmed a subscription to reduce the data sent when loading, thanks for your advice.  When drilling down the XHR bar I found some functions taking some long time to run, but since all code is minified I'm not able to understand which part of my code it is... Any advice to relate it to my written code?

Comment: That sounds like a package. Method names will remain in clear text with their original names so they are easy to spot. Try setting a breakpoint at the start of the long running xhr to see what it's actually doing.

Comment: [The Bottom-Up tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference#bottom-up) might help you quantify what events are taking up the most time.

Comment: I’m not familiar with Meteor, but is there anything in your build workflow that’s minifying or obscuring your JS?

Comment: Questions on SO need to be specific and answerable. The only thing you can get from what you supplied are wild guesses and opinions, neither of which are allowed on SO, a fact based Q&A platform.

Comment: Yeah this question is better placed on the Meteor forums, but it is a good question generally, even if not suited for StackOverflow

Comment: @KayceBasques In the bottom-up tab I noticed the Scripting is taking 1.3s.  Iniside it I have a Function Call (1.2s) with two items occupping most of the time: 1.Animation Frame Fired (.5s) which mostly have inside the meteor packages loading scripts /  2.XHR Ready State Change (.7s!)  What is doing that?

Also in the summary I have discovered I have 6s of idle time! Should that mean my server is responding slow?  Checking other websites like facebook, the size of the downloaded items are bigger and much more faster than mine (Using the network profiling).

Answer (score 0):

@Ruben, let us know what you learned, if you were able to reduce meteor load time.

You are absolutely right with your assumption for **Meteor build** - it will perform the JavaScript code minification.

You should try running the performance recorder on **localhost** and - in the best case - it should give you a more detailed insight on how things really are.